# Extracting lots of data from SQL Server into parquet file efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, parquet, pyarrow

I have data in SQL Server and I need to save it in parquet format. Right now I'm using pyodbc and pyarrow libraries for this.

As there are serveral million rows, I'm doing it by using queries within a for loop that retrieves chunks of data using a where clause on the SQL server that search for periods in `YYYYMM` format like `201501, 201502, ..., 202310` and then grouping them together by year and saving it as parquet like `example_2023.parquet`.

The code is:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                    'SERVER=SERVER;'
                    'DATABASE=DATABASE;'
                    'UID=USER;'
                    'PWD=PASS')

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """SELECT DISTINCT [PERIOD]
FROM [RIESGO_MODELO].[dbo].[MP_INCUMPLIMIENTO]
ORDER BY [PERIOD] ASC
;
"""
cursor.execute(query)

periods = [str(i[0]) for i in cursor.fetchall()]

query_ = """SELECT [PERIOD]
            , [FIELD1]
            , ...
            , [FIELDN]
        FROM [RIESGO_MODELO].[dbo].[MP_INCUMPLIMIENTO]
        WHERE PERIOD = 
        """

rows_cons = []

for period in periods:

    month = period[-2:]

    if month != '12':

        query = query_ + period + ';'

        rows = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()

        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

        rows_cons = rows_cons + rows

    else:

        query = query_ + period + ';'

        rows = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()

        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

        rows_cons = rows_cons + rows

        table = list(zip(*rows_cons))

        pa_table = pa.table(table, names=columns)

        pq.write_table(pa_table, r'local_path\example_{}.parquet'.format(period[:4]))

        rows_cons = []

        del table

        del pa_table

cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

Currently it's taking around 20+ minutes to extract and save each parquet file. Is there any improvement I can make to reduce this time?

Comment: Have you tried polars?